# How to get object value from listview adapter position

Tags: android, listview, listview-adapter

How to get value from adapter position, i have code in below:

```
CategoriesXmlParser categoryXmlParser = new CategoriesXmlParser();
List<HashMap<String, Object>> categories = null;

try {
  categories = categoryXmlParser.parse(reader);
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
}

String[] from = { "name", "image" };
int[] to = { R.id.nama_category, R.id.logo_category };

final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                    categories, R.layout.per_item_category, from, to);

mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
    Object obj = mListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    String value = obj.toString();
    Log.d("MyLog", "Value is: "+value);
    String name = // how code to get name value.
  }
});
```

If I look log it on logcat in the MyLog I get as:

> Value is: {position=12,
>   image_path=http://192.168.103.121/xml/icon.png,
>   link=http://192.168.103.121/xml/category.php?kat_id=13, name=Category
>   13}

So my question, I want to get value from name and stored to variable String name, I want to get just "Category 13" in String name. Because I want to passing it to another activity.

Comment: Well, what object type do you fill your adapter with? You can simply cast the result of `getItem()` to that and then use whatever accessors you implemented to retrieve the value for the `name` field.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Looks like you made ​​the object with hashmap, such blablabla.put("name", "value")?? If yes. Try this:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        Object obj = mListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        String value = obj.toString();
        Log.d("MyLog", "Value is: "+value);
        String name = // how code to get name value.
    }
});
```

Change to:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);
            String name = (String) obj.get("name");
            Log.d("Yourtag", name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
value = value.substring(value.indexOf("name=")+5,value.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
listID.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Object obj=listID.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                        String str=obj.toString();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item is= "+str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the adapter data via `AdapterView<?> parent`

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            final Filedata mnotes = (Filedata) parent
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Filedata.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did:-

```
lvHomePage.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                       Transaction selectedFromList =(Transaction)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                       Log.d("val:",selectedFromList.getDate());
                       Log.d("val:",selectedFromList.getMobile_no());
                   }
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

listID.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{

```
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
```

HashMap<String, Object> sdsa = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);
Log.e("IndentNo", (String) sdsa.get("IndentNo"));
Log.e("IndentId", (String) sdsa.get("IndentId"));

```
                }
            });
```