# Get element from the selected item in the listView

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Stackoverflow has really helped me get to this level. Thank you all.

Basically, I want to get an element (sub-part not the whole data) from the selected item in a ListView. I've read here that it could be done using Cursors but no success. This is the associated snippet:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    Cursor member = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Click ListItem Number "+member.getString(2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
```

`parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` gives me the (Array, I suppose):

`{name="xyz_name", uname="xyz_user", desig="xyz_desig"}` correctly.

I want to, suppose, fetch `uname`from this, so, have used Cursor to fetch it but the above snippet is giving the error,

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to android.database.Cursor`

Adding detail: I'm getting the text associated with the listView item correctly. What I actually want a sub-part of the data retrieved. For example the data retrieved is obviously an array containing a name and his role. Now, I just want to fetch the 'role' element in the array. Since, the data is retrieved as an array, what I've searched on net is that I can use Cursors to retrieve different elements. Hope you got me now.

There's seem to be a silly syntax error by my side. If you have any alternatives, please tell.

Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get object value from listview adapter position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393334/how-to-get-object-value-from-listview-adapter-position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding your case, `getItemAtPosition(position)` is returning you an `Object`.

The answer posted by @Charuka Silva might not be working for you as you may have used hashmap object something like `HashMap<String,String> obj = new HashMap<String,String>();`

So, the solution is to use HashMap again for getting the returned object and using `get("key")` function to retrieve the value associated with it. I think this is what you want:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
//Use HashMap here
                    HashMap<String, Object> member = (HashMap<String, Object>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


//Use obj.get("key") here to retrieve the value associated with the "key"
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"member.get("uname"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
```

I had a similar problem in my Minor Project and an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14406964/6884255) by @user1068963 helped me. Adding Link.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

go with the simple way

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          Object listItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Click ListItem Number"+listItem.getString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } 
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, but

`Cannot resolve method getString()`

The only method associated with `Object` Studio giving hint of is `getClass()`

Comment: Object is a generic type. what important is position.  once you get it you know what is the position you clicked right? If you want to get the value of a text view in that list item no need to use Object, use what you want.. if its a TextView  tv = list.getItemAtPosition(position); then you can get it to a string ... did you get that

Comment: I'm getting the text associated with the listView item correctly. What I actually want a sub-part of the data retrieved. For example the data retrieved is obviously an array containing a name and his role. Now, I just want to fetch the 'role' element in the array. Since, the data is retrieved as an array, what I've searched on net is that I can use Cursors to retrieve different elements. Hope you got me now.